# Please help. The program for generating random numbers is not working

Tags: c

I am writing a program which have to generate N random not repeating numbers

the prototype should be voidrandom_int(int array[], int N);
it is not having any errors but it is not working. Not even giving any number

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


void random_init(int array[], int N)
{
   srand(time(NULL));
   int i, j;
   array[0]=rand()%N;
   for(i=1;i<N;i++)
   {
       array[i]=rand()%N;
       if(array[i]==0)
           array[i]=1;

       for(j=0;j<i;j++)
       {
           if(array[i]==array[j])
           break;
       }
       if((i-j)==1)
           continue;
       else
           i--;
   }
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[5], i, N;
    N=5;
    random_init(a,N);
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    printf("%d    ", a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for properly formatted question **with compilable code**

Comment: Does it exit?  Or is it in an infinite loop?

Comment: -1 for properly formatted code with no question whatsoever. "It's not working" is a statement, and a vague one.

Comment: On the use of `rand() % n`: http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx

Answer (score 3):

1. This part makes no sense:

   ```
   if(array[i]==0)
      array[i]=1;
   ```

   It will limit your choices to N-1 numbers (1 to N-1), out of which you try to find N numbers without repetition - leading to an infinite loop.
2. ```
   if((i-j)==1)
      continue;
   ```

   Here you probably want `if (i==j)` instead, to check if the previous loop ran to completion.

A faster and simpler way to generate the numbers 0..N-1 in a random order, is to put these numbers in an array (in sequential order), and then use [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to shuffle the array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how can I check if(i==j ) if my previous loop ends with for(j=0;j<i;j++)????

Comment: @Kasha: The loop ends when the loop condition is no longer correct -- in this case, when `j>=i` (which will only happen when `j==i`, because it is incremented by 1 each time).

Answer (score 0):

**This method is biased. Do not use it other than for educational purposes.**

<s>Other than Ficher-Yates, which uses another array, you can use the method of going through all the available numbers and find a "random" spot for them (effectively "initializing" the array twice). If the spot is taken, choose the next one. Something like this, in pseudo-code:</s>

```
fill array with N
for all numbers from 0 to N-1
    find a random spot
    while spot is taken (value is N) consider next spot /* mind wrapping */
    set value in current spot
```

Comment: Thanks. I really like this idea... will try it)

Comment: This will result in some configurations having a different probability of being chosen than others. For example, with 3 elements, 0,1,2 will be twice as likely to be chosen than 0,2,1.

Comment: Hmmm ... right. Thanks @interjay. I wish I could downvote myself :D

Comment: @Kasha: do try the Fisher-Yates method. The method above is biased as interjay warned: after placing the 0, the program has 3 spots for the `1`. In two of those spots the outcome will be 0,1,2; it will be 0,2,1 for only 1 of the spots